# Real Analysis sets with same liminf and limsup

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\{E_k\}$ be a sequence of measurable sets uniformly bounded in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\liminf (E_k)=\limsup(E_k)$
what can we say about
$\lim_{k\rightarrow +\infty} |E_k|$?
If we remove the uniformly bounded hypothesis, what can we say about $\lim_{k\rightarrow +\infty} |E_k|$ ?

Comment: How do you define $\lim\inf$, $\lim\sup$ of sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_limit

Answer (score 0):

The limit set existing (which is implied by your equality) seems to be a rather strong condition since by the indicator function definitions you can see that for an element $x$ to be in the limit set $E$, it must *eventually* be in $E_k$.

Notice that measurability of the limit set is implied (cf the last bullet in the "Properties" section), and the first statement in the "Probability Uses" section should imply that $\lim|E_k|=|E|$, and I would guess the unbounded case is the same since convergence in this respect is pretty strong. That said, I'm not sure how to prove it and picking the optimistic answer is always dangerous...

Comment: "I would guess the unbounded case is the same" Actually, *counterexamples* in the unbounded case abound, say $A_{2n}=(n,n+1)$, $A_{2n+1}=(n,n+2)$.

Comment: @Did good call.

Comment: @Did why not just take $A_n=(n,n+1)$? Then the limit set is the empty set and $|A_n|=1$ for all $n$?

Comment: Why not take an example where $|A_n|$ does not even converge?

Comment: @Did so the only thing I wonder about that situation is if the required equality holds, since it seems like existence of a limit set is implied by it and doesn't have any boundedness requirement?